# Circles under inversions; mobius trans.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Could you please confirm or refute this argument:

I'm trying to apply inversion (the map $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$) to the disk centered at $1+i$ and radius $\sqrt2$, so the disk whose boundary is going through the origin. 
There's this bit about orientation of that I don't think understand. Here's the argument:

If the boundary circle is going through the origin, then this will be mapped to a line not going through the origin. I take the points $2i$ and $2$, apply the map, get $-i/2$ and $1/2$. So the boundary of the disk will be mapped to the circle going through these two points and the point at infinity, so a straight line going through $-i/2$ and $1/2$. What happens to the inside of the circle? Do those points get mapped to the right or left side of this this line?

I remember reading that inversions change orientation, but I can't, for the life of me, find that reference.

If I travel on the circle positively, starting at the origin, I go $0 \to 2 \to 2i$, so in the image I go $\infty \to 1/2 \to -i/2$. If the inversion didn't change the orientation, then I should have the inside of the cirle on the left of that line in that direction, so chunk below this line. Otherwise it will be mapped to the chunk above the line. Which one is it?

I strongly suspect that it is supposed to be the lower chunk, since intuition tells me so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest way is to apply the inversion map to a point inside the circle (e.g. $1+i$) and see which side of the line it comes out on.

Comment: Of course, how silly of me! Thanks, this is chystal clear now!